# Can't display function result

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to make a dropdownlist based on data I get from the database but I can't display them. Could someone lend me a hand?

```
include '../opdrachten/connectionPDO.php';

function Select()
{

$query =$db->prepare("SELECT naam FROM opdracht4");
$query->execute();

foreach ($query as $row)
{
echo '<option value="'.$row['naam'].'">"'.$row['naam'].'"</option>';    
}
} 

<select name="projectleider">   
<?php Select();  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is data in your result set? Also, Do you want to display the result on the same page or external?

Comment: There are several problems with this code, but what's more important is: **what exactly is not working? do you get an error? what does it say?**

Comment: External, but i included the class page. I don't get an error at all when i fetch it. It just doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `$db` into the function to get it in scope.

```
include '../opdrachten/connectionPDO.php';

function Select($db)
{

$query =$db->prepare("SELECT naam FROM opdracht4");
$query->execute();

foreach ($query as $row)
{
echo '<option value="'.$row['naam'].'">"'.$row['naam'].'"</option>';    
}
} 

<select name="projectleider">   
<?php Select();  ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the values from function. Try this,

```
function Select()
{

  $query =$db->prepare("SELECT naam FROM opdracht4");
  $query->execute();

 $str = '<option value="">Select anyone</option>';
 foreach ($query as $row)
 {
  $str.= '<option value="'.$row['naam'].'">"'.$row['naam'].'"</option>';    
 }
 return $str;
}
```

While calling try this,

```
<select name="projectleider">   
<?php echo Select();  ?>
</select>
```